# How to pass API key authorization in header while consuming an API using Node Js?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, authorization

I am working on consumption of API using Node Js. I am stuck at a point as I do not know how to consume an authorized API. Kindly tell me where did I go wrong?

**Following is the code I wrote while doing this:**

```
    var express = require(express);

    var app = express();

    var http = require('http');

    var myAPIKey= 'SharedAccessSignature sr=e91e0083-2c2b-47de-91bc-8c0b5f4fd3fd&sig=j9tCl4xKFjTpfNrHt%2BD4xQjVt15SxXSPM4bXj4sO6Zw%3D&skn=BMC004Connect&se=1620277640046'


    var options = {

        host:'bmc.azureiotcentral.com',

        port: 80,

        path:'/api/preview/devices',

        method:'GET',

        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic" + myAPIKey
          }

    };

    http.request(options, function(res){
        var body ='';

        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function(){
            var values = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(values);
        });

    }).end();
```

**and I am getting the following error:**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- E:\ReactNative\try\app.js
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)?[39m
?[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)?[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ReactNative\try\app.js:1:15)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
  requireStack: [ ?[32m'E:\\ReactNative\\try\\app.js'?[39m ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Install `express` in you project

```
npm i express
```

You can check if it's installed by finding it in the `packege.json` and/or if its in the `node_module` dir

Second, Use string to import the modules.

```
var express = require('express');
```

This will take care of your error.

---

About the `consume an authorized API`. The header looks good but you need to add space between the `Basic` and the value.

```
     headers: {
         "Authorization": "Basic " + myAPIKey
     }
```